# TFS 2017 Agent: and error occured while sending the request

Tags: tfs

I have a personal laptop running Windows 10 Home edition.
I log into the laptop with my hotmail account.
I installed TFS 2017 locally and I have it woring in the browser. I can clone the repository and push to it.

Now when I try to setup the build I have to add an agent. I downloaded the agent and when I try to configure it I get this:

PS D:\TfsAgent> .\config.cmd

> > Connect:

Enter server URL > http://localhost:8080/tfs/
Enter authentication type (press enter for Integrated) >
Connecting to server ...
An error occurred while sending the request.
Failed to connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit
Enter server URL >

Soo, for some reason an error happens when it tries to connect to the server.
I do not see any verbose parameter to the config.cmd or any logs for that matter.

Any reasons why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Home edition of Windows does not support the full TCP stack nor does it have all of the tools expected by applications. You need Professional edition at a minimum.

I would recommend that you go to http://tfs.visualstudio.com and let Microsoft provision you a free TFS instance that you can use.