# Azure DevOps self-hosted pipelines agent cannot connect to server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am testing Azure DevOps Pipelines and just installed the agent on a Windows computer.

However when I run `config.cmd`, it cannot connect to my Azure DevOps server:

```
PS C:\agent> .\config.cmd

>> Connect:

Enter server URL > https://my-azure-devops-server.com
Enter authentication type (press enter for PAT) >
Enter personal access token > ****************************************************
An error occurred while sending the request.
Failed to connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit
```

How can I check what happens? Could it be related to the fact that the server uses a self-signed HTTPS certificate?

Comment: This is a normal error message and we could not provide more help. You may need to do more troubleshooting, like did you have system proxy setup on the agent server? Or windows version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104319/tfs-2017-agent-and-error-occured-while-sending-the-request

Comment: 1. The DevOps server is a Windows 2012 R2 on the Azure cloud.
2. The agent is a Windows 10 laptop on the home network.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the self-signed certificate. Once I replaced it with a certificate from ZeroSSL, that problem disappeared.

Comment: Can I ask how you replaced the self-signed certificate?